# How to forward ipv4 broadcast packets between 2 computers on 2 different subnets?

Tags: routing

I use my linux server as a primitive router.  Currently I have it able to use masquerading to talk to the outside world (using a fixed IP), but about a year or two ago, I upgraded the link between my primary workstation and the server to 10Gb.   Everything else in my internal net is on a 1Gb net.  For the most part traffic goes from the internal nets to the outside.  Both use a 192.168 subnet, with the 1Gb talking on 192.168.3.0/24 and the 10Gb on 192.168.4.0/24.

Occasionally, the subnets need to talk to each other (printer is only on
the 1Gb net), and I use iptables FORWARDING rules to shuffle packets between the two nets.  I.e.

Due to the large speed difference, I can't use a bridge -- the traffic on the
10Gb would swamp the 1Gb link, so I use iptable's FORWARDING rules when I need to talk to specific addresses on the 1Gb net.

Recently I ran into an app that talk to other computers w/a UDP broadcast  to '255.255.255.255'.  It may use unicast after initial setup, I'm not sure as I've never it actually work.

The app only runs on 2 computers, so I have tried forwarding the broadcast
to the alternate net, only when it comes from one of those 2 ip addresses,
but so far, have had no luck getting the broadcast address to be forwarded 
between the two subnets.

It seems like it should be 'easy' (which probably means I'm missing things).

The server is setup as the default route and routing 'normal packets' 
between the internal nets or from either of them externally works fine.

Do ethernet adapters need to have a separate address setup to even 'hear'
the broadcast, (as normally, a subnet broadcast looks like "192.168.x.255").

I've tried using source & destination rules to forward the 255.255.255.255 broadcasts to the "other internal net", if it comes from one of the two
internal hosts that are trying to communicate this way, and though I see the broadcast go out on the local net (with the computer doing the sending also sending out a response to itself).  But no sign of the address being accepted or routed through the server.

As mentioned, normal addresses are routed 'fine' (ping, remote desktop, CIFS file sharing), but not the broadcast address.

Is there some special magic needed for broadcast addrs?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Due to the large speed difference, I can't use a bridge -- the traffic on the 10Gb would swamp the 1Gb link"_: this is wrong, unless your traffic is 100% layer2-broadcast. Sorry, but you're lacking the difference between an "hub" and a "switch". Hence, I second what clearly explained by @ron-maupin in its comments, below.

Answer (score 4):

[RFC 922, BROADCASTING INTERNET DATAGRAMS IN THE PRESENCE OF SUBNETS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc922), specifically disallows forwarding the Limited Broadcast (Local Broadcast `255.255.255.255`) from one LAN to another which would result in bridging. You say you don't want to bridge because one LAN would swamp another, but allowing the Limited Broadcast from one LAN to another would do exactly that.

> The address 255.255.255.255 denotes a broadcast on a local hardware
> network that must not be forwarded.  This address may be used, for
> example, by hosts that do not know their network number and are
> asking some server for it.

Broadcasts interrupt every host on a LAN, and every host must read and process a broadcast, causing a performance hit. This rule helps protect against DoS attacks since broadcasts can be used to bring down a LAN.

There is also the IP network (directed) broadcast which, by default, doesn't propagate from one LAN to another (DoS, again), but which can be configured to do so. This would be the `192.168.3.255` and `192.168.4.255` addresses on your LANs.

If there is a way around this, it is contrary to the RFC, and it could result in unpredictable network behavior.

Comment: Right, but since it can't be propagated, it can't be used as a DoS weapon (e.g. you can't send the broadcasts to another LAN) which is why sending the broadcasts from one LAN to another is forbidden. You want to do something which is against the foundation of networking.

Comment: Quoting RFC's to regulate behavior on a private net seems a bit unhelpful.  There is no protection needed against a DoS attack as it's a private internal net -- forwarding the broadcast would "interrupt" 1 additional host (the 1 host on the 10Gb link that is the desired target of the packet.  Any hosts on the .3. net are already interrupted, so that point is moot.  Right now, I am getting the predictable network behavior of "failure".  So any behavior other than complete failure could be an improvement.

Comment: I am merely explaining why you can't get it to work. You can accept the fact that the RFC specifically disallows the behavior you want, or not, but network stacks and equipment are designed to meet the RFCs. You could do something like a server which receives the broadcast, packages it as a unicast, and sends it to another server on the the other LAN which then reverses the process. In essence, you bridge the LANs.

Comment: Bridging does exactly  what the RFC prohibits -- i.e. it takes 2 different local networks -- not hardware connected and does exactly what RFC 922 says you cannot do.  Are you claiming bridging violates internet standards?  Bridging was designed to do exactly what you claim is prohibited.  So I don't buy it that bridging is disallowed.    I need a *subset* of bridging -- due to the speed difference between the nets.  Attempting to bridge those nets would VERY likely result in unpredictable network behavior and/or DoS for the entire 1G net.

Comment: Is it preferable to just setup a bridge that WOULD harm network traffic, or is there a workaround.  The RFC is broken -- as it is disallowing a subset of something that is already commonplace.

Comment: The RFC is what it is for over 30 years. Anyone, including you, is free to submit an RFC for publication which allows the behavior you want, but it is doubtful it will be published, or you can write your own network stack. The solution for sending broadcasts from one LAN to another is the network broadcast, which the RFCs allow. You want to use a LAN application across LANs, something for which it is apparently not designed. Sending Limited Broadcasts from one LAN to another does bridge the LANs, and you say that is not what you want.

Comment: A LAN, or VLAN, is a _broadcast domain_. If you allow broadcasts between LANs, then you have merged two broadcast domains into a single LAN. Bridges (switches) are the layer-2 devices which pass broadcasts within a LAN. Layer-2, including broadcasts, is bounded by layer-3 (router). You are wanting to turn the router into a bridge (switch).

Comment: Are you saying the only thing that bridging does is forward local broadcasts? I.e. when the 10Gb is doing 200-500MB/s file transfers to the server, those won't be sent to the 1Gb net?  Currently, using forwarding, the server only forwards traffic between the nets when the source and destination are on separate nets.   Are you saying that wouldn't change and only broadcast traffic would be forwarded?

Comment: Unicast traffic is only forwarded to the port on a switch for which is it destined. A switch (bridge) learns the MAC (layer-2) addresses of the individual hosts, and forwards traffic directly to the port on which the host is connected. Broadcasts are sent to all the ports, so broadcasts are the only traffic which really spans the entire LAN. It is not unusual to have multiple switches in a LAN, some of which have 10 Gb ports while others have 1 Gb ports, and some even have both.

Comment: There are no switches, per se, on the 10Gb net -- it's a direct cable between both computers.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be under the impression that merely having devices of mixed speeds will present problems for the lower speed devices. Without getting into the specifics about how switches, hubs and bridges work, I'll just say that it simply isn't likely that this software is capable of transmitting 10Gbps of broadcast traffic on the network. Any one of us here could give you countless examples of networks where devices of mixed speeds (10Mbps, 100Mbps, 1Gbps, 10Gbps) all happily co-exist in the same physical network. Simply put, I would be dumbstruck if your software was capable of transmitting 10Gbps of broadcast traffic on the network. You've designed your network based on a slightly mistaken understanding of networking. My suggestion would be to put all of your devices on the same physical network, in the same subnet, and be done with it.

Comment: I have 10/100/1G BUT, I don't have a 10G infrastructure -- only the 2 computers are hooked to that.  No, I don't get 10Gb, but I do often get over 200Mb (on CIFS -- not broadcast).  I was under the mistaken impression of thinking along the lines of a hub, not a switch or card-to-card.  My bad.